# Por que no se ejecuta mi job en pgAgent?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, pgadmin, jobs

Estoy practicando con postgresql y uso pgAdmin, desarrolle un job para un update a un registro, sin embargo no esta funcionando y a nivel de las estadisticas veo que todas salieron con status F, pero en mis logs no veo el motivo de error, de hecho no veo directamente que me salga algun error, de igual forma revise la excepciones en pga_exception y no me aparece ningun registro. Probe con otro job para la base de postgres ejecutando un insert y ahi si me funciona pero al querer hacer cualquier step para mi otra base no funciona

Mi step:

```
UPDATE "ProcesosEvaluacion" SET "Estado" = 'Inactivo' WHERE "Id_Proceso_Evaluacion" = (SELECT MAX("Id_Proceso_Evaluacion") FROM "ProcesosEvaluacion") AND "Fecha_Fin" <= NOW();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis logs, estos dos ultimos se registraron cuando lo ejecute

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy probable que tengas pgagent instalado en la base de datos postgres, por eso te funciona ahi, pero hacer operaciones en otras bases de datos vas a tener que utilizar [FDW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) o [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html), pues PostgreSQL no te permite acceder a otras bases a y travez de SQL plano, tienes que usar alguna extensión como las comentadas para poder hacer esa operacion

Comment: me funciono usando dblink y seleccionando la base de postgres en la configuracion del job, te lo agradezco! Para que funcionara tuve que poner en el dblink mi usuario y pass para que le permita el acceso asi como el nombre de la base, puerto y host